# Passing a multidimensional array as a pointer to a function in C gives an unexpected result

Tags: c, function, pointers, gcc, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C, and I am trying to write a function which counts the number of 1's along each column in a matrix made out of 1's and 0's. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *countCols(int *output, int rows, int cols, int **matrix[5][5])
{
  /*(int *output) is the pointer which we want the output stored at.
   *(int rows) is the number of rows in our matrix. This is found to be 5 at runtime
   *(int cols) is the number of cols in our matrix. This is also found to be 5 at runtime.
   *(int **matrix[5][5]) is a matrix containing the 1's and 0's.
   */
  int colnum;
  int rownum;
  int counts[cols];
  for (colnum = 0; colnum < cols; colnum ++)
  {
    for (rownum = 0; rownum < rows; rownum ++)
    {
      counts[colnum] += matrix[rownum][colnum];
    }
  }
  /*
   *We store the result in output.
   */
  output = counts;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /*
   *First, we create our matrix.
   */
  int matrix[5][5] = {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                      {1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
                      {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                      {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                      {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}};
  int *Cs;
  countCols(Cs, 5, 5, matrix); 
  /*Here, we tally up our 1's column by column.*/
  int i;
  printf("The column counts are:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", Cs[i]);
    /*Next, we print the counts on separate lines.*/
  }
  /*Finally, we return 0*/
  return 0;
}
```

So, I was expecting:

```
The column counts are:
3
1
4
3
3
```

However, to my surprise, I got:

```
The column counts are:
1768709983
1935631202
1953653108
1767992671
1600061550
```

What's going on here? It's also worth noting that, when I compiled, I got these warnings:

```
C.c In function 'countCols':
C.c:12.22: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
        counts[colnum] += matrix[rownum][colnum];

C.c In function 'main':
C.c:27.23: warning: passing argument 4 of 'countCols' from incompatible pointer type
     countCols(Cs, 5, 5, matrix);

C.c:3:7: note: expected 'int ** (*)[5]' but argument is of type 'int (*)[5]'
 void *countCols(int *output, int rows, int cols, int **matrix[5][5])
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Just to be clear, I'm passing a pointer to the matrix, not the matrix itself, into countCols.

Comment: Pay attention to the warnings. An array is not a pointer, a pointer is not an array, and a multidimensional array is not a pointer-to-pointer. [Link to relevant C-FAQ section](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) (By the way, what led you to believe that `int **[5][5]` can *possibly* be the same as `int **`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything, so the return type should be `void`, not `void*`.

First of all the prototype of your function should be something like this:

`void countCols(int *output, int rows, int cols, int matrix[5][5])`

it could be improved though.

Then, inside the body of the function you do:

`output = counts;`

where you set your pointer to an array that has local scope, thus it will be de-allocate when the function terminates. However, your pointer, `Cs`, will not preserve changes, since it's passed by value to the function.

Use dynamic allocation instead and don't forget to free it when you are done.

With dynamic allocation your function should be like this (notice that the prototype differs from the one I suggested above):

```
// Pass a pointer to the integer pointer for 'output'
void countCols(int **output, int rows, int cols, int matrix[5][5])
{
  int colnum;
  int rownum;
  // PERFORM DYNAMIC ALLOCATIONS and USE 'output', instead of 'count'
  *output = malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
  for (colnum = 0; colnum < cols; colnum ++)
  {
    for (rownum = 0; rownum < rows; rownum ++)
    {
      (*output)[colnum] += matrix[rownum][colnum];
    }
  }

  // NO NEED FOR THIS
  // output = counts;
}
```

and the main, where the calling and the free-ing of the memory are remarkable:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /*
   *First, we create our matrix.
   */
  int matrix[5][5] = {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                      {1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
                      {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                      {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                      {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}};
  int *Cs = NULL;
  countCols(&Cs, 5, 5, matrix);
  /*Here, we tally up our 1's column by column.*/
  int i;
  printf("The column counts are:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", Cs[i]);
    /*Next, we print the counts on separate lines.*/
  }

  free(Cs);
  /*Finally, we return 0*/
  return 0;
}
```

---

Appendix

As The Paramagnetic Croissant said:

"Pay attention to the warnings. An array is not a pointer, a pointer is not an array, and a multidimensional array is not a pointer-to-pointer."

Make sure you take a good look at the Arrays and Pointers section from [here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/).

Comment: `output = counts;` won't result in a dangling pointer, actually. The change in the value of `output` isn't reflected outside the caller, because it's local to the callee. There would be a problem iff `output` was an `int **` and OP wrote `*output = counts;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the following function declaration:)

```
void countCols(int *output, int rows, int cols, int ( *matrix )[5] );
```

instead of

```
void *countCols(int *output, int rows, int cols, int **matrix[5][5]);
```

because you call it like

```
countCols(Cs, 5, 5, matrix);
```

Take into account that you did not allocate memory that would be pointed to by pointer `Cs`

```
int *Cs;
```

However inside the function you assign it the address of the first element of a local array.

So the program has undefined behaviour.

You could write simply

```
int Cs[5];
```

and inside the function use it instead of the local array.

So remove the definition of the local array

```
  int counts[cols];
```

from the function and use directly parameter output

Comment: This would solve the problem too and I like that there is an alternative solution from mine here. :) However, I think that the prototype you suggest still needs tuning. Check my answer.

Comment: It relies on the fact that `matrix[5][5]` is equivalent to `*(matrix + row)[col]` or `*(*(matrix + row) + col)`. From a prototype standpoint, `row` is simply `0` while the `col` index must be specified reducing the syntax to `*matrix[5]` or `(*matrix)[5]` for readability.

Comment: @G. Samaras  I do not understand what "tuning" you are speaking.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin is your comment targeting me? If so, I didn't mean that, but I was talking (Vlad) for the return type of the prototype. I feel that we are spending more time on this question than the OP. :P

Comment: Yes, Vlad's prototype is correct. What do you mean by 'tuning'?